# How can I use package classes and call packages from Oracle11gr2 stored procedure in certain schema?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

When a stored procedure begins with

```
4 create or replace procedure user0.import
5 is
6   f1 utl_file.file_type;
```

compiler throws an error `Error(6,6): PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' must be declared`.

But if I replaced `is` with `declare` and ran the same as anonymous block selecting everything after line 4, it would work fine and import data as expected. This is runnning under `SYS AS SYSDBA`. Also it would compile fine if `user0` schema was not used.

Why cannot I as sysdba compile a procedure in a user0 schema?

Comment: Never ever EVER use SYS for this type of thing. Create another user and give it the privs it needs.

Comment: That was the purpose of user0

Answer (score 1):

Try granting directly execute to utl_file to user0:

```
grant execute on util_file to user0;
```

Then try to recompile the code.

Comment: But won't that lead to a situation, where user0 will now be able to play with importing any files they wanted, instead of being constrained to what the stored procedure was designed for? It almost feels like I would have to keep procedure under sysdba and grant user0 access instead. Just need to wrap my head around this security model.

Comment: Correct, but I thought that you wanted exactly that. I would do it in a different way: 1. Don't store application code in the sys schema, create another application user, let's say app_owner. 2. Grant app_owner the grants it needs to compile and run the code and then, if user0 is supposed to be able to execute app_owner's procedures, 3. grant execute on app_owner.procedure to user0.

Comment: I am weary of the proxy users as they represent configuration management hazard. When compiling code as superuser, should not compiled unit inherit super-user permissions to the objects it used? Otherwise what's the point of compliation - we could just give up on super-users and compliation and allow regular users to run their code in a line-by-line interpreter.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. What I mean is to separate schema owner and application user. These posts explain the concept: [Schema Owners and Application Users](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/schema-owners-and-application-users.php) and [Grants to users](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::p11_question_id:1372403341772).